# How do I add an .ics calendar event to Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api, expressionengine, icalendar

I am creating an Expression Engine Calendar using Solspace's Calendar module which exports .ics files. I would like for users to be able to click on a link to add events to their Google Calendar.

Google search we too broad and I need some more specific direction on how this might be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention that you are using a module that exports the ics files.

Generally link should then be to the ics file (or the code that produces the ics file dynamically).

Then when the user clicks the link, the browser sees it is an ics file and depending on the user's settings will prompt an action (usually to add to their calendar).

If you **specifically only want to add to their google calendar**, then you need to generate the sorts of link hrefs you see at this test site:
http://test.icalevents.com/calendar-of-all-events/

It has example of "add whole calendar to google) and "add just an event to google" (as well as the more general ics links).

Hope that makes it clearer?

Comment: That icalevents.com link is dead. Would be great of someone could inline the example that was supposed to be there.

Comment: It's up again, basically add to google is a link   like this: http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&text=JGs%20Event&dates=20130511T160000Z/20130511T170000Z&trp=false&details=Fantastic%0A

Comment: It's down again:)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to have links to add individual events to a visitor's calendar, follow the Google developer documentation here: http://www.google.com/googlecalendar/event_publisher_guide_detail.html

Then just use your various field variables to build the link to spec in your template.

Comment: Hi Derek, I read that. I need something dynamic that will be able work with hundreds of events. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "dynamic"? Do you mean hundreds of events at once? Are you talking about adding a calendar *subscription*?

Comment: Derek, yes, this is a full-blown calendar using the Solspace module.